# Malformed Rails JSON and jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to return some data for a json request in rails and I was wondering if the data being returned is malformed. Here is a shortened example:

```
[{"company":{"name":"A"}},{"company":{"name":"B"}}]
```

I always thought that when returning json it should describe the root element and plurals, so it should return something more like:

```
{"companies":[{"name":"A"},{"name":"B"}]}
```

Here are the questions - Is there any way I can get my json to come out in that format?  Is that even the correct format or does each company node need to be labeled as well? Do I have to create a custom view to get my results?  What is the best way to get jQuery to loop the data in the current format? Right now I'm using:

```
format.json  { render :json => @companies.to_json() }
```

To render the results.

Thanks in advance for any help/advice.

Comment: Still unclear - Is the only way for Rails to generate the second example to make a custom view? (This is for an index view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like the [JSend specification](http://labs.omniti.com/labs/jsend). I came up with this myself before I realized it had been done before, because I've found it tremendously useful to have a standard response container for JSON services.

Here's how I would rewrite your server response:

```
format.json do
  render :json => {
    :status => 'success',
    :data => {
      :companies => @companies
    }
  }
end
```

There are times when you need to alter the attributes that are generated when converted to `JSON`. In these cases, I just use `map`:

```
format.json do
  render :json => {
    :status => 'success',
    :data => {
      :companies => @companies.map do |company|
        hash = company.attributes
        hash['address'] = company.address
        hash.delete('secret')
        hash
      end
    }
  }
end
```

A little more verbose than `to_json`, but it's more flexible and works just as well in Rack middleware.

Comment: Still retains the "company" key for every single object.  It also seems that if I just use "@companies" I lose the specificity I get with the to_json method, no?

Comment: @sshefer You can remove the company key by setting `ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false` in an initializer. If I need to alter the attributes, I just use `map` instead.

Comment: Thanks Adam - I actually ended up using "as_json" in my model to define how the default json response should look and then send some additional options as needed.  This answer was the closest to what I was looking for!

Comment: @sshefer that is also a valid approach, and probably better in cases where you need the same `to_json` response in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid JSON.  However, I would agree with you that the second is preferable.  It's less redundant, since the first has an unnecessary object layer and repeats the company key.  But a more subtle benefit is that the second protects you from [JSON hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx), which is only possible when the root structure is an array.

To loop the first, use e.g.

```
$.getJSON(url, functon(resp)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++)
  {
     var company = resp[i].company;
     var name = company.name;
  }
});
```